# O que é o duplo sentido na expressão "conversa fiada"?

Tags: significado, expressões, expressões-idiomáticas

Na discussão sobre o nome da nossa sala de chat o @bfavaretto [propôs](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/107/155) *"Conversa fiada"* com um comentário que "tem um duplo sentido não óbvio".

Eu entendi essa frase como *chat* ou *small talk*. O que é o segundo sentido aqui, ele que aparentemente me escapa?

Comment: Obrigado pela correção @Math. Esse verbo *propor* é mt estranho :|

Comment: Michal, realmente ninguém pensa nesse segundo sentido que a expressão poderia ter, porque ela é uma expressão idiomática, com sentido fixado. Mas o Jorge B. na resposta dele entendeu o meu raciocínio, é por causa dos sentidos do verbo "fiar". PS: se você sabe conjugar o verbo *por*, fica fácil conjugar *propor* ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conversa fiada pode ter o sentido  de "conversa com o objetivo de ludibriar a pessoa",  como por exemplo "você é muito linda e muito simpática bla bla bla". 
Não vejo outro sentido para a expressão. Só se for no sentido literal, conversa refinada.

Comment: Foi por aí mesmo que eu pensei quando comentei que teria um duplo sentido. A palavra "fiar" isoladamente significa "confiar", mas a expressão "conversa fiada" não tem nada a ver com isso (talvez venha de "fiado").

Comment: @bfavaretto Fiar também significa fazer fio: fiar lã ou linho. Foi sempre por aí que eu entendi _conversa fiada_: como um fio, contínuo e sem fim. Segundo o Priberam _fiar_ também significa _tecer_ e, figuradamente, tramar, maquinar, urdir. Agora _fiada_ significar _refinada_?!

Comment: @Jacinto  *tecer* faz muito mais sentido, é bem possível que seja mesmo a origem do termo.

Comment: Mas aqui em Portugal, representado por mim e pela minha irmã, _conversa fiada_ pode estar associada a desculpa esfarrapada ou tentativa de impingir alguma coisa, mas não a burla. Achei o _ludibriar_ do Jorge B. um bocado forte.

Comment: @Jacinto desculpa esfarrapada ou tentativa de impingir alguma coisa é ludibriar, ludibriar é diferente de burla.

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, ludibriar é mais fraco que burlar. Foi um exagero. Eu quase não uso _ludibriar_, e na minha sensibilidade, uma desculpa esfarrapada ou uma tentativa de impingir, ou conversa fiada em geral, são demasiado transparentes para merecerem ser descritas por _ludibriar_.

Comment: Conversa fiada pode ser uma conversa que se estende mas que não responde à alguma questão inicial. Por exemplo, uma pessoa quer saber se você vai sair com ela. Então você fala um monte de coisa pois não quer dizer logo que não. Depois de muito tempo diz que não vai. Então a pessoa percebe que esteve sendo enrolada e diz: " - Então por que me faz perder tempo com essa conversa fiada?".

Comment: "Ela ficou o dia inteiro de conversa fiada com a vizinha", ou seja, ela conversou, fofocou, bateu papo, etc. Mas pode significar bravata, papo-furado - "não me venha com conversa fiada!".

Answer (score 0):

"Fiado" é quando a gente compra algo pra pagar depois. É uma atitude portanto que gera dúvida no recebedor. Logo, a conversa fiada é uma conversa sem muita credibilidade. Um "papo-furado", sem seriedade ou a respeito de coisas questionáveis.

Comment: Isso em inglês seria loose talk.